# is this a taylor series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a problem where I seem to have gotten to this series$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k(k+1)}$$

but the question is making me feel like there should be some sort of "better" form, so I was wondering if there was a well known name for this series? (Perhaps it is some sort of Taylor Series that I'm not recognizing) (where $t>0)$, but I suspect if I can restrict $|t|<1$, I may be able to get it to somewhat resemble a Taylor Series, but this is just a hunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Taylor series for $|t|<1$.  In fact we can write

$$f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k+1}=-\log(1-t)+1+\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}$$

Answer (score 6):

Writing $\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} = \dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+1}$, you can show that this is the Maclaurin series of 
$$ \left(\dfrac{1}{t}-1\right) \ln(1-t) + 1$$